# SQL Server : Then executed when When is false?

Tags: sql, case

I have the following case statement

```
case 
   when [cross].WEIGHT is not null and len([cross].WEIGHT) > 0
      then [cross].WEIGHT
   when pricesvc.INDV_WEIGHT is not null and len(pricesvc.INDV_WEIGHT) > 0
      then pricesvc.INDV_WEIGHT
   when pricesvc.PKG_WEIGHT is not null and len(pricesvc.PKG_WEIGHT) > 0 and pricesvc.PS_LGCY_QTY3 is not null and len(pricesvc.PS_LGCY_QTY3) > 1 and right(pricesvc.PS_LGCY_QTY3,1) = 'M'
      then CONVERT(FLOAT, REPLACE([pricesvc].[PKG_WEIGHT],',','')) / (CONVERT(FLOAT, REPLACE(left([pricesvc].[PS_LGCY_QTY3],len([pricesvc].[PS_LGCY_QTY3])-1),',','')) * 10000)
   when pricesvc.PKG_WEIGHT is not null and len(pricesvc.PKG_WEIGHT) > 0 and pricesvc.PS_LGCY_QTY3 is not null and len(pricesvc.PS_LGCY_QTY3) > 0 
      then CONVERT(FLOAT, REPLACE([pricesvc].[PKG_WEIGHT],',','')) / CONVERT(FLOAT, REPLACE([pricesvc].[PS_LGCY_QTY3],',',''))
   when pricesvc.PKG_WEIGHT is not null and len(pricesvc.PKG_WEIGHT) > 0 
      then pricesvc.PKG_WEIGHT
   else '0.01'
end as 'weight',
```

The very first `when` is true, however the third `when/then` is still executed and throws an error

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to float.

I added the `When` test for null and zero length but the `then` convert is still executed and gives error. Seems strange, as I thought a false condition would not be executed

Comment: If you comment out the line in question, does the query still throw errors?

Comment: if i take out all the when's except the first it runs without error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Else clause have 0.01 instead of the varchar '0.01' and see if that helps. Additionally what are the datatypes for [cross].WEIGHT and pricesvc.INDV_WEIGHT and pricesvc.PKG_WEIGHT? You would need to cast them as float too. Essentially the error is not because the third condition is being executed its because your SQL failed to parse due to the fact that you have different datatypes in the results of your case statement that cannot be implicitly converted.

Try This  -

```
case 
   when [cross].WEIGHT is not null and len([cross].WEIGHT) > 0
      then CONVERT(FLOAT, REPLACE([cross].WEIGHT,',',''))
   when pricesvc.INDV_WEIGHT is not null and len(pricesvc.INDV_WEIGHT) > 0
      then then CONVERT(FLOAT, REPLACE(pricesvc.INDV_WEIGHT,',','')) 
   when pricesvc.PKG_WEIGHT is not null and len(pricesvc.PKG_WEIGHT) > 0 and pricesvc.PS_LGCY_QTY3 is not null and len(pricesvc.PS_LGCY_QTY3) > 1 and right(pricesvc.PS_LGCY_QTY3,1) = 'M'
      then CONVERT(FLOAT, REPLACE([pricesvc].[PKG_WEIGHT],',','')) / (CONVERT(FLOAT, REPLACE(left([pricesvc].[PS_LGCY_QTY3],len([pricesvc].[PS_LGCY_QTY3])-1),',','')) * 10000)
   when pricesvc.PKG_WEIGHT is not null and len(pricesvc.PKG_WEIGHT) > 0 and pricesvc.PS_LGCY_QTY3 is not null and len(pricesvc.PS_LGCY_QTY3) > 0 
      then CONVERT(FLOAT, REPLACE([pricesvc].[PKG_WEIGHT],',','')) / CONVERT(FLOAT, REPLACE([pricesvc].[PS_LGCY_QTY3],',',''))
   when pricesvc.PKG_WEIGHT is not null and len(pricesvc.PKG_WEIGHT) > 0 
      then pricesvc.PKG_WEIGHT
   else 0.01
end as 'weight',`
```

Comment: tried but did not help.  but you are onto something... If I leave just the first "when" with the single quotes around 0.01 it runs, but with only the first "when" and no quotes it give convert to numeric error.

Comment: Updated answer with more details. Hope it helps.

Comment: all the table data types are varchar.  I will try casting

Comment: casting fixed it!!  Thank you so much!